# Поправить надпись в нижнем левом углу изображения

Tags: html5, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в моём примере поправить стиль, чтобы у каждого фото надпись была в левом нижнем углу. У меня так получается, только когда фотки в один столбик, а нужно - 'в линию'.

---

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background: #E8DDCF;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
}


#content {
    display: inline-block;/* иначе не видно рамки;*/
 width:100%; 
    background: #F3E7D8;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
}


#fotos img {
 border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
    float: left;  /* иначе - все в один столбец;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#fotos img:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.container {
    position: relative;
}


.bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: blue;
}


.f {
 width: 12.33%;
 height: 9%;
    border: 1px solid #F3E7D8;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="menu"> </div> 

<div id='content'>
<div id='fotos'>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC01.jpg" alt="01"><div class="bottomleft">q</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC02.jpg" alt="02"><div class="bottomleft">w</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC03.jpg" alt="03"><div class="bottomleft">e</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC04.jpg" alt="04"><div class="bottomleft">r</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC05.jpg" alt="05"><div class="bottomleft">t</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC06.jpg" alt="06"><div class="bottomleft">y</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC07.jpg" alt="07"><div class="bottomleft">u</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC08.jpg" alt="08"><div class="bottomleft">i</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC09.jpg" alt="09"><div class="bottomleft">o</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC10.jpg" alt="10"><div class="bottomleft">p</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float: left;` и ширину нужно задать `.container`, а не изображению.

```css
#menu {
 width:100%;
 height:30px;
    background: #E8DDCF;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
}


#content {
    display: inline-block;/* иначе не видно рамки;*/
 width:100%; 
    background: #F3E7D8;
    border: solid 1px #E8DDCF; 
}


#fotos img {
 border: solid 1px #E8DDCF;
    
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#fotos img:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.container {
    position: relative;
  
    width: 12.33%;
    float: left;  /* иначе - все в один столбец;*/
}


.bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: blue;
}


.f { 
    width: 100%;
 height: 9%;
    border: 1px solid #F3E7D8;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="menu"> </div> 

<div id='content'>
<div id='fotos'>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC01.jpg" alt="01"><div class="bottomleft">q</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC02.jpg" alt="02"><div class="bottomleft">w</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC03.jpg" alt="03"><div class="bottomleft">e</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC04.jpg" alt="04"><div class="bottomleft">r</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC05.jpg" alt="05"><div class="bottomleft">t</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC06.jpg" alt="06"><div class="bottomleft">y</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC07.jpg" alt="07"><div class="bottomleft">u</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC08.jpg" alt="08"><div class="bottomleft">i</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC09.jpg" alt="09"><div class="bottomleft">o</div></div>
<div class="container"><img class="f" src="DSC10.jpg" alt="10"><div class="bottomleft">p</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Elena Semenchenko, спасибо, работает как надо.

Comment: @Kromster, ок))) Увлеклась))